# com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable error while building the apk file

Tags: flutter, dart, build, apk

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile".

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 34s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           96.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
PS D:\Flutter-SmartStaff> flutter build apk

Building with sound null safety

Font asset "LineIcons.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 384876 to 960 bytes (99.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 6672 bytes (99.6% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 42s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           43.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

I tried to build apk, i tried changing org.gradle.jvmargs but still throw same error.

Answer (score 2):

Check build.gradle file at android => app => build.gradle

```
 signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
 
        debug {
 
        }
    }
 
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
 
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
 
        }
    }
}
```

Also read https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app for key.properties file